# Batch scripting return most recent folder name with string match in text file

Tags: xml, string, powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I created a little batch script that looks through all the folders with a sequential name given a root folder and returns the latest created:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir C:\RootFolder\FolderName_* /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
SET a=%%i
GOTO :found
)
echo No folder found
goto :eof
:found
echo Most recent directory: %a%
```

Now I have to enhance it by returning the most recent directory that contains the following string

```
Name="Test" Value="completed"
```

**within a file** called test.xml in its subfolder called test.

F.e. I have

1. C:\RootFolder\FolderName_1\  --- created today --- with test\test.xml but not containing that string
2. C:\RootFolder\FolderName_2\ --- created yesterday --- but not finding test\test.xml
3. C:\RootFolder\FolderName_3\ --- created three days ago with test\test.xml and with the matching string within
4. C:\RootFolder\FolderName_4\ --- created four days ago with test\test.xml and with the matching string within

Then the folder that should be returned is number 3.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest created directory, with your pattern, using powerShell:

```
Get-Childitem FolderName_* | sort CreationTimeUTC
```

Extending it a little bit further, to consider test.xml:

```
Dir RootFolder_* | 
Sort CreationTimeUtc |
Select -Property FullName, @{Name="XmlFile";Expression={ $_.FullName + "\test.xml"}} |
Where { Test-Path $_.XmlFile } | 
Select FullName, @{Name="XmlContent";Expression={ Get-Content ($_.XmlFile)}} |
Where { $_.XmlContent -match "Value=""completed""" } |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName -First 1
```

You could also tune it a little bit, to get the newest xml file which contains your pattern:

```
Dir RootFolder_*\test.xml | 
Where { Test-Path $_.FullName } | 
Select FullName, @{Name="XmlContent";Expression={ Get-Content ($_.FullName)}} |
Where { $_.XmlContent -match "Value=""completed""" } |
Select -First 1
```

Comment: Your 'tuned' code never sorts, so it just returns the first result, which I imagine would be the first alphabetically. Also, he stated that it is "FolderName_*\Test\Test.xml". Easy fixes =)

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd rather use wildcards and the `Select-String` cmdlet to do that in PowerShell. I will line-break and indent after pipes for ease of reading since this gets long.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\RootFolder\FolderName_*\Test\Test.xml' |
    Where{(Select-String -simplematch 'Name="Test" Value="completed"' -quiet)} |
    Select -Expand Parent |
    Select -Expand Parent |
    Sort -Descending LastWriteTime |
    Select -First 1
```

So let's break that down line-by-line:

1. Get-ChildItem gets a file object for all of the Test.xml files stored within your folders' "test" subfolders.
2. It then enters a `Where` statement that searches those files for the string 'Name="Test" Value="completed"' using `Select-String` with the `-Quiet` switch so `Select-String` just outputs True/False depending on if it found the string in the file. So that `Where` statement only passes those files that contain the string on down the pipe.
3. Next we expand the `Parent` property, giving us the 'Test' folder that each of those files is stored in.
4. Then we do it again, giving us the 'FolderName_*' folder that the 'Test' folder is stored in.
5. Then we sort by LastWriteTime.
6. Lastly we select the first one.

That's it, it gives you exactly what you were looking for as a folder object to do with as you please (move it, rename it, simply display it, whatever).